# aplication crash and take me this errors

Tags: android

I have the following problem. Applications crash and shows error sladnje, ideas are welcome

```
09-07 20:10:55.896: D/dalvikvm(1347): GC freed 782 objects / 55712 bytes in 109ms
09-07 20:10:56.066: D/dalvikvm(1347): GC freed 162 objects / 7192 bytes in 47ms
09-07 20:10:56.116: W/dalvikvm(1347): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
09-07 20:10:56.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1347): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-9 exiting due to uncaught exception
09-07 20:10:56.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1347): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 20:10:56.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at aa.bb.cc.Panel.onDraw(Panel.java:372)
09-07 20:10:56.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at aa.bb.cc.TutorialThread.run(Panel.java:502)
09-07 20:10:56.146: I/dalvikvm(1347): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
09-07 20:10:56.218: E/dalvikvm(1347): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
09-07 20:10:57.916: I/Process(1347): Sending signal. PID: 1347 SIG: 9
```

AndroidPaint.java

package aa.bb.cc;

```
public class AndroidPaint extends Activity {

    static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

    public Shape currentGraphicObject;

    public int ShapeObject_to_be_created;

    public  int ShapeLine = 1;
    public  int ShapeRect = 2;
    public  int ShapeCircle = 3;
    public int ShapeOval = 4;
    public  int ShapeFreehand =5;
    public  int ShapeErase = 6;

    public  Paint mPaint;

    public  float BrushWidth;

    public double[] color;
    public Panel p;
    public int number_of_graphicObjects;

    public boolean shapemenuclicked;
    public boolean colormenuclicked;
    public  boolean erasemenuclicked;
    public boolean brushwidthmenuclicked;

    public ArrayList<Shape> graphicobjects;

    private Bitmap wallPaperBitmap;

    static WallpaperManager wallpaperManager;

    public  int wallpaperHeight;

    public     int wallpaperWidth;

    private String mImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/androidpaint";

    File file;



    public  Canvas bitmapCanvas;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       

        color = new double[3];

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);




        graphicobjects = new ArrayList<Shape>();


        currentGraphicObject = new Shape();



        mPaint = new Paint();

        InitializePaint();

        shapemenuclicked = false;
        colormenuclicked = false;

        BrushWidth = 3;




        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();


        wallpaperHeight = display.getHeight();

        wallpaperWidth = display.getWidth();


        wallPaperBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(wallpaperWidth, wallpaperHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(wallPaperBitmap);
    }


    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        p.surfaceDestroyed(p.getHolder());

    }

    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        p.surfaceDestroyed(p.getHolder());
        /*graphicobjects.clear();
        number_of_graphicObjects = 0;*/
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        p.surfaceDestroyed(p.getHolder());

        graphicobjects.clear();
        number_of_graphicObjects = 0;
    }


   public void onResume(){
       super.onResume();

    }

    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();


        p = new Panel(this,null);
       // setContentView(p/*new Panel(this)*/);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
      p=(Panel)findViewById(R.id.yourID) ;


      /*   if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null)
         {
            //GraphicObject = (Shape)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
             graphicobjects.set(number_of_graphicObjects-1, (Shape)getLastNonConfigurationInstance());
         }
         int n = graphicobjects.size();
         if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null)
         {
            //GraphicObject = (Shape)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            //graphicobjects.set(number_of_graphicObjects-1, (Shape)getLastNonConfigurationInstance());
            //graphicobjects.addAll((Shape)getLastNonConfigurationInstance());
             Object[] temp = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
                graphicobjects.set(i,(Shape)getLastNonConfigurationInstance());
            }
         }*/
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //savedInstanceState.p
    }

    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    }

    //test
   /* public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() 
    {
     // if (GraphicObject != null) // Check that the object exists
          //return(GraphicObject);
        //if(!graphicobjects.isEmpty())
            return graphicobjects.toArray();//.get(number_of_graphicObjects-1);
     // return super.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance();
    }*/

    private void InitializePaint()
    {
        mPaint.setDither(true);

        mPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(100, 100,100));

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(BrushWidth);  

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
        }
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.itemLine:
        ShapeObject_to_be_created = ShapeLine;
        //GraphicObject = new Line();
        shapemenuclicked = true;
        erasemenuclicked = false;
        brushwidthmenuclicked = false;
        return true;

    case R.id.itemFreehand:
        ShapeObject_to_be_created = ShapeFreehand;
        //GraphicObject = new FreeHand();
        shapemenuclicked = true;
        erasemenuclicked = false;
        brushwidthmenuclicked = false;
        return true;

    case R.id.itemRectangle:
        ShapeObject_to_be_created = ShapeRect;
        //GraphicObject = new Rectangle();
        shapemenuclicked = true;
        erasemenuclicked = false;
        brushwidthmenuclicked = false;
        return true;

    case R.id.itemCircle:
        ShapeObject_to_be_created = ShapeCircle;
        //GraphicObject = new Circle();
        shapemenuclicked = true;
        erasemenuclicked = false;
        brushwidthmenuclicked = false;
        return true;

    case R.id.itemOval:
        ShapeObject_to_be_created = ShapeOval;
        //GraphicObject = new Oval();
        shapemenuclicked = true;
        erasemenuclicked = false;
        brushwidthmenuclicked = false;
        return true;

    case R.id.itemColor:
        LaunchColorPicker();
        colormenuclicked = true;
        erasemenuclicked = false;
        brushwidthmenuclicked = false;
        return true;

    case R.id.itemErase:
        ShapeObject_to_be_created = ShapeErase;
        //GraphicObject = new Erase();
        erasemenuclicked = true;
        shapemenuclicked = false;
        colormenuclicked = false;
        brushwidthmenuclicked = false;
        //BrushWidth = 8;
        return true;

    case R.id.itemBrushWidth3:
        BrushWidth = 3;
        brushwidthmenuclicked = true;
        return true;

    case R.id.itemBrushWidth4:
        BrushWidth = 6;
        brushwidthmenuclicked = true;
        return true;

    case R.id.itemBrushWidth5:
        BrushWidth =9;
        brushwidthmenuclicked = true;
        return true;

    case R.id.itemBrushWidth6:
        BrushWidth = 12;
        brushwidthmenuclicked = true;
        return true;

    case R.id.itemSetWallPaper:
        //wallPaperBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(p.getWidth(),p.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bitmap temp = p.getDrawingCache(true);
        //wallPaperBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(temp);
        //Canv
        //Canvas canvas = p.getHolder().lockCanvas();
        //p.getHolder().lockCanvas().drawBitmap(wallPaperBitmap, 0,0, mPaint);
        //p.draw(canvas);
        //try{
            //getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(wallPaperBitmap);
        //}
        //catch(IOException e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
        //}
        //p.saveScreenshot();
        //wallPaperBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.p.getWidth(), this.p.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //File file = new File(mScreenshotPath + "/" + "screeshot.jpg");
        /*try{
        FileInputStream fIS = new FileInputStream(file); 
        //wallPaperBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fIS);
        fIS.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Panel", "FileNotFoundException", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Panel", "IOEception", e);
        }*/




        return true;

    case R.id.itemSaveImage:

         Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
          SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMMddHmmss");
          String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
          file = new File(mImagePath + "/" + dateNow +".9.png");
          FileOutputStream fos;
          try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            wallPaperBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Panel", "FileNotFoundException", e);
          } 
          catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Panel", "IOEception", e);
        }
    }

    return false;
} 

private void LaunchColorPicker(){
    Intent launchcolorpicker = new Intent();
    launchcolorpicker.setClassName("somitsolutions.training.android.colorpicker", "somitsolutions.training.android.colorpicker.ColorPicker");
    launchcolorpicker.setAction("somitsolutions.training.android.colorpicker.android.intent.action.COLORPICKER");
    launchcolorpicker.addCategory("CATEGORY_DEFAULT");
    launchcolorpicker.setType("vnd.somitsolutions.color/vnd.somitsolutions.color-value");

    try {
        startActivityForResult(launchcolorpicker,REQUEST_CODE);

    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("IntentExample", "Activity could not be started...");
    }   
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent result ) {

    if(requestcode == REQUEST_CODE){
        if(resultcode == RESULT_OK){
            color[0] = (result.getDoubleArrayExtra("somitsolutions.training.android.colorpicker.color_of_the_shape"))[0];
            color[1] = (result.getDoubleArrayExtra("somitsolutions.training.android.colorpicker.color_of_the_shape"))[1];
            color[2] = (result.getDoubleArrayExtra("somitsolutions.training.android.colorpicker.color_of_the_shape"))[2];
            //mPaint.setColor(Color.rgb((int)color[0], (int)color[1],(int)color[2]));
            //GraphicObject.setPaintColor((int)color[0], (int)color[1],(int)color[2]);

            //test
            //onStart();
        }
    }
}}
```

Palete.java

```
    package aa.bb.cc;



public   class Panel extends SurfaceView implements  Callback {
private Shape currentGraphicObject;

AndroidPaint a;




    public Panel(Context context,  AttributeSet attributeSet) {

        super(context, attributeSet);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);


        _thread = new TutorialThread(getHolder(), this);

        setFocusable(true);
    Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }

    public Panel(Context context) {

        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

      _thread = new TutorialThread(getHolder(), this);

        setFocusable(true);
     Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }

    public ArrayList<Shape> getGraphicObjects(){
        return a.graphicobjects;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //if(shapemenuclicked == true && erasemenuclicked == false){
            synchronized (_thread.getSurfaceHolder()) {

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                    if(a.shapemenuclicked == true && a.erasemenuclicked == false){
                        //if(GraphicObject instanceof Line){
                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeLine){
                            currentGraphicObject = new Line();

                            ((Line) currentGraphicObject).getBegin().setX(event.getX());
                            //((Line)(GraphicObject).getBegin().setX(event.getX()));//.setX(event.getX());
                            //begin.setY(event.getY());
                            ((Line) currentGraphicObject).getBegin().setY(event.getY());
                        }

                        //if(GraphicObject instanceof FreeHand){
                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeFreehand){ 
                            currentGraphicObject = new FreeHand();

                            ((FreeHand)currentGraphicObject).getPath().moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());

                            ((FreeHand)currentGraphicObject).getPath().lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());

                        }


                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeRect){ 

                            currentGraphicObject = new Rectangle();
                            Point temp = new Point(event.getX(), event.getY());
                            ((Rectangle) currentGraphicObject).settemppointOfOneEndRectangle(temp);
                        }


                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeCircle){   
                            currentGraphicObject = new Circle();
                            ((Circle)currentGraphicObject).getOneEndOfTheCircle().setX(event.getX());
                            ((Circle)currentGraphicObject).getOneEndOfTheCircle().setY(event.getY());
                        }


                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeOval){
                            currentGraphicObject = new Oval();
                            ((Oval)currentGraphicObject).getoneEndOfTheOval().setX(event.getX());
                            ((Oval)currentGraphicObject).getoneEndOfTheOval().setY(event.getY());
                        }

                    }

                    if(a.shapemenuclicked == false && a.erasemenuclicked == true){

                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeErase){    
                            currentGraphicObject = new Erase();

                            ((Erase)currentGraphicObject).getPath().moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());

                            ((Erase)currentGraphicObject).getPath().lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());

                        }
                    }

                }
                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

                    if(a.shapemenuclicked == true && a.erasemenuclicked == false){


                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeFreehand){
                            ((FreeHand)currentGraphicObject).getPath().lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        }


                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeLine){

                        }


                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeRect){

                        }
                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeCircle){

                        }

                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeOval){

                        }
                    }

                    if(a.shapemenuclicked == false && a.erasemenuclicked == true){

                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeErase){
                            ((Erase)currentGraphicObject).getPath().lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());


                    }

                }


                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    if(a.shapemenuclicked == true && a.erasemenuclicked == false){

                        //if(GraphicObject instanceof Line){
                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeLine){ 


                            ((Line) currentGraphicObject).getEnd().setX(event.getX());
                            ((Line) currentGraphicObject).getEnd().setY(event.getY());

                            Point temp_begin = ((Line)currentGraphicObject).getBegin();
                            Point temp_end = ((Line)currentGraphicObject).getEnd();
                            ((Line) currentGraphicObject).setBegin(temp_begin);

                            ((Line)currentGraphicObject).getPath().moveTo(temp_begin.getX(), temp_begin.getY());
                            ((Line)currentGraphicObject).getPath().lineTo(temp_end.getX(), temp_end.getY());
                            //currentGraphicObject.setrgb((int)color[0],(int)color[1],(int)color[2]);
                        }


                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeFreehand){
                            ((FreeHand)currentGraphicObject).getPath().lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());

                            ((FreeHand)currentGraphicObject).getGraphicsPath().add(((FreeHand)currentGraphicObject).getPath());

                        }


                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeRect){
                            float tempX = ((Rectangle) currentGraphicObject).gettemppointOfOneEndRectangle().getX();

                            float tempY = ((Rectangle) currentGraphicObject).gettemppointOfOneEndRectangle().getY();
                            float tempX1 = event.getX();
                            float tempY1 = event.getY();
                            if(tempX<tempX1 && tempY>tempY1){
                                ((Rectangle)currentGraphicObject).getPath().addRect(tempX, tempY1, tempX1, tempY, Path.Direction.CW);
                            }
                            if(tempX<tempX1 && tempY<tempY1){
                                ((Rectangle)currentGraphicObject).getPath().addRect(tempX, tempY, tempX1, tempY1, Path.Direction.CW);
                            }
                            if(tempX>tempX1  && tempY>tempY1){
                                ((Rectangle)currentGraphicObject).getPath().addRect(tempX1, tempY1, tempX, tempY, Path.Direction.CW);
                            }
                            if(tempX>tempX1 && tempY<tempY1){
                                ((Rectangle)currentGraphicObject).getPath().addRect(tempX1, tempY, tempX, tempY1, Path.Direction.CW);
                            }

                        }

                        //if(GraphicObject instanceof Circle){
                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeCircle){
                            float tempX1 = ((Circle)currentGraphicObject).getOneEndOfTheCircle().getX();
                            float tempY1 = ((Circle)currentGraphicObject).getOneEndOfTheCircle().getY();
                            float tempX2 = event.getX();
                            float tempY2 = event.getY();
                            double temp = Math.pow((tempX1-tempX2),2) + Math.pow((tempY1-tempY2),2);
                            float radius = (float)Math.sqrt(temp)/2;
                            ((Circle)currentGraphicObject).getPath().addCircle((tempX1 + tempX2)/2,(tempY1 + tempY2)/2, radius, Path.Direction.CW);

                            (int)color[1],(int)color[2]);
                        }


                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeOval){ 
                            float tempX = ((Oval)currentGraphicObject).getoneEndOfTheOval().getX();
                            float tempY = ((Oval)currentGraphicObject).getoneEndOfTheOval().getY();
                            float tempX1 = event.getX();
                            float tempY1 = event.getY();

                            if(tempX<=tempX1 && tempY>=tempY1){
                                ((Oval)currentGraphicObject).getRectangle().set(tempX,tempY1,tempX1,tempY); 
                            }

                            if(tempX<=tempX1 && tempY<=tempY1){

                                ((Oval)currentGraphicObject).getRectangle().set(tempX,tempY,tempX1,tempY1);

                            }

                            if(tempX>=tempX1  && tempY>=tempY1){

                                ((Oval)currentGraphicObject).getRectangle().set(tempX1,tempY1,tempX,tempY);

                            }

                            if(tempX>=tempX1 && tempY<=tempY1){

                                ((Oval)currentGraphicObject).getRectangle().set(tempX1,tempY,tempX,tempY1);
                            }

                            //RectF r = ((Oval)GraphicObject).getRectangle();
                            ((Oval)currentGraphicObject).getPath().addOval(((Oval)currentGraphicObject).getRectangle(), Path.Direction.CW);
                            //((Oval)GraphicObject).getPath().addOval(r, Path.Direction.CW);
                        }
                    }

                    if(a.shapemenuclicked == false && a.erasemenuclicked == true){
                        //if(GraphicObject instanceof Erase){
                        if(a.ShapeObject_to_be_created == a.ShapeErase){
                            ((Erase)currentGraphicObject).getPath().lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());

                            ((Erase)currentGraphicObject).getGraphicsPath().add(((Erase)currentGraphicObject).getPath());

                        }
                    }

                    if(a.colormenuclicked == false && a.shapemenuclicked == true){
                        currentGraphicObject.setrgb(100,100,100);   
                    }
                    if(a.colormenuclicked == true && a.shapemenuclicked == true){
                        currentGraphicObject.setrgb((int)a.color[0],(int)a.color[1],(int)a.color[2]);
                    }

                    if(a.erasemenuclicked == true && a.colormenuclicked == false){
                        currentGraphicObject.setrgb(0,0,0);
                        //mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
                    }

                    if(a.brushwidthmenuclicked == true){//  || erasemenuclicked == true){
                        currentGraphicObject.setStrokeWidth(a.BrushWidth);
                    }
                    a.graphicobjects.add(currentGraphicObject);

                    a.number_of_graphicObjects++;
                }

                /*if(colormenuclicked == false && shapemenuclicked == true){
                    currentGraphicObject.setrgb(100,100,100);   
                }
                if(colormenuclicked == true && shapemenuclicked == true){
                    currentGraphicObject.setrgb((int)color[0],(int)color[1],(int)color[2]);
                }

                if(erasemenuclicked == true && colormenuclicked == false){
                    currentGraphicObject.setrgb(0,0,0);
                    //mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
                }

                if(brushwidthmenuclicked == true){//  || erasemenuclicked == true){
                    currentGraphicObject.setStrokeWidth(BrushWidth);
                }
                graphicobjects.add(currentGraphicObject);

                number_of_graphicObjects++;*/
            }


      return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            for(int i = 0; i<a.number_of_graphicObjects; i++){

                Shape currentGraphicObject = a.graphicobjects.get(i);


                    a.mPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(currentGraphicObject.getrgb()[0], currentGraphicObject.getrgb()[1], currentGraphicObject.getrgb()[2]));
                    a.mPaint.setStrokeWidth(currentGraphicObject.getStrokeWidth());


                if(currentGraphicObject instanceof FreeHand){
                    for (Path path : ((FreeHand)currentGraphicObject).getGraphicsPath()) {
                        canvas.drawPath(path,a.mPaint);
                        a.bitmapCanvas.drawPath(path,a.mPaint);
                    }
                }

                else if(currentGraphicObject instanceof Erase){
                    for (Path path : ((Erase)currentGraphicObject).getGraphicsPath()) {
                        canvas.drawPath(path, a.mPaint);
                        a.bitmapCanvas.drawPath(path, a.mPaint);
                    }   
                }

                else{
                    canvas.drawPath(currentGraphicObject.getPath(),a.mPaint);

                    a.bitmapCanvas.drawPath(currentGraphicObject.getPath(),a.mPaint);

                }
            }

      }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {


    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        _thread.setRunning(true);
        _thread.start();

    }


    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        boolean retry = true;
        _thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                _thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }


class TutorialThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private Panel _panel;
    private boolean _run = false;

    public TutorialThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Panel panel) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _panel = panel;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return _surfaceHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (_run) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {

                }
            } finally {

                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you narrow down your code to the relavant parts. Which line the error is thrown etc.

Comment: this       for(int i = 0; i<a.number_of_graphicObjects; i++){
       and this       _panel.onDraw(c);

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your variable `a` is null and I can't see where he was initialized. So initialize it and the NullPointerException has gone.

One more thing. Your code is very extensive and declaring variables 'a' or 'b' and package names like 'aa.bb.cc' doesn't looks like a nice code. Programming is for humans to understand not machines ;)

Comment: At the `onStart` I only see a variable `p` declared and initialized. And your `a` variable is declared in the `Panel` class which extends `SurfaceView` and that means you can't have a `onStart` method there!

Comment: where I have to move on start method

Comment: You're very welcome. I can't tell you exactly what to do. You know your code's logic better than me, I guess :) Please, accept my answer if it really helped you.